# wxpython drag-and-drop dataobjectcomposite

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, wxpython

I've spent more time than i'd like to admit on this and i'd really like
some help on understand the wxPython drag and drop inside and out.

Note: Yes I have read the documentations and unfortunately i am having a hard time tracing and understanding them. And yes code is oversimplified for sharing and testing purposes.

### Please and Thank You!

## Details

```
- Python 2.7.6
- Wxpython 3.0.0.0 msw (classic)
```

## I want to achieve the following

```
1. Have a view that calls dropSource.doDragDrop() that makes use of a wx.CompositeDataObject
2. Have a window you can drop in that reads wx.CompositeDataObject
3. The wx.CompositeDataObject components would contain generic DataObjects (no TextDataObject, etc... )
```

### Question is

1. How do i send and retrieve data from CompositeDataObjects?

### Current Code

[image: Screen Shot]

```
import wx

#Bare Bones App for Testing Only
app = wx.App()
someParentWindow = wx.Frame(None)
someParentWindow.Show(True)

#Drag Implementation
def _drag(e):
        if e.Dragging():
                dropSource = wx.DropSource( e.GetEventObject() )
                textdf = wx.DataFormat( wx.DF_TEXT )
                textdo = wx.DataObjectSimple()
                textdo.SetData("asd")
                data = wx.DataObjectComposite()
                data.Add( textdo )
                dropSource.SetData(data)
                result = dropSource.DoDragDrop()
                print result

text = wx.StaticText( someParentWindow, label="Drag Me")
text.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, _drag)

#Drop Implementation
class DropTarget(wx.PyDropTarget):
        def __init__(self, windowTarget):
                super(DropTarget,self).__init__()
                self.window = windowTarget
                textdf = wx.DataFormat( wx.DF_TEXT )
                self.textdo = wx.DataObjectSimple()
                self.do = wx.DataObjectComposite()
                self.do.Add( self.textdo )
                self.SetDataObject( self.do )

        def OnData(self,x,y,d):
                #Get the composite data
                pass


textctr = wx.TextCtrl( someParentWindow, pos=(3,20) )
textctr.SetDropTarget( DropTarget( textctr ) )


#MainLoop
app.MainLoop()
```